# SQL select statement with 3 tables of joins

Tags: sql, join

I have three tables `blocksequences` `blocksequenceparts` `partpositions`
here are some examples, respectively:

```
blocksequenceid P1 P2 P3 P4
E006-T001-S054-S036 E006 T001 S054 S036

blocksequenceid partid
E006-T001-S054-S036 E006
E006-T001-S054-S036 T001
E006-T001-S054-S036 S054
E006-T001-S054-S036 S036

partpositions
E006 P1
T001 P2
S054 P3
S054 P4
S036 P3
S036 P4
```

as you can see S054 and S036 can be in positions P3 or P4 (in different blocksequence this can be seen)

I want to create this table:

```
blocksequenceid partid positionid
E006-T001-S054-S036 E006 P1
E006-T001-S054-S036 T001 P2
E006-T001-S054-S036 S054 P3
E006-T001-S054-S036 S036 P4
```

but instead I'm getting

```
blocksequenceid partid positionid
E006-T001-S054-S036 E006 P1
E006-T001-S054-S036 T001 P2
E006-T001-S054-S036 S054 P3
E006-T001-S054-S036 S054 P4
E006-T001-S054-S036 S036 P3
E006-T001-S054-S036 S036 P4
```

so for this specific blocksequence S054 is in position P3 and S036 is in position P4 only, but I am getting all possible positions for these parts irrespective of blocksequence.

This is the statement I've been using:

```
create table test as( 
select blocksequenceparts.blocksequenceid, blocksequenceparts.partid, partpositions.positionid
from blocksequences right outer join blocksequenceparts on blocksequences.blocksequenceid=blocksequenceparts.blocksequenceid  left outer join partpositions on blocksequenceparts.partid=partpositions.partid
order by blocksequenceid);
```

Not sure what to do to get the result I want. I'm open to having to change my tables if that would help.

Comment: In your example, only partid S054 has multiple partpositions... if it's true that only one partid will have multiple partpositions, then the solution is just a convoluted process of elimination. But if multiple partids could be in the same partposition, there is not enough information in the data to solve. For instance, if both S054 and E006 both had partpositionids of 3 and 4, more than one solution could exist.

Comment: I think someone had edited my code.. anyway the idea is some parts can be in multiple positions depending on the blocksequence. So what should I add to these tables to make it possible to select correctly?

Comment: The database fundamental you're overlooking is that records do not inherently have position in a table. So when S054 and S036 are both viable for position 3 and 4, nothing tells set-based logic which one should have which. Now, if your blocksequences are _arriving_ and you can add a timestamp, that can be used to clarify position.

Comment: what if I were to add columns P1, P2, P3, P4 to my blocksequences table where P1 would be E006, P2 would be T001, P3 would be S054 and P4 would be S036.. can I use that table now to select the right position for that part?

Answer (score 1):

How are you supposed to decide which part goes in which position?  The data you have provided results in six rows.  The real solution is for `partpositions` to have only one row per part or for `blocksequenceparts` to include the position as well as the part.

This query doesn't fix your problem, but it does at least simplify the query:

```
select bs.blocksequenceid, bsp.partid, pp.positionid
from blocksequences bs left outer join
     blocksequenceparts bsp
     on bs.blocksequenceid = bsp.blocksequenceid  left outer join
     partpositions pp
     on bsp.partid = pp.partid
order by bs.blocksequenceid;
```

First, note how much easier the query is to write and to read when you use table aliases.

Second, the rules for outer joins.

- You almost always want `left join`.  In fact, I pretty much never use `right join`.  And I *never* mix `left join` and `right join`, unless the purpose is to illustrate some strange behavior.
- `Left join` makes a lot of sense . . . keep all rows in the first table, even if there are no matches in subsequence tables.
- Clauses (`where`, `group by`, `order by`) should generally be using columns from the first table.

You can get one row per sequence/partposition by using aggregation:

```
select bs.blocksequenceid, max(bsp.partid), pp.positionid
from blocksequences bs left outer join
     blocksequenceparts bsp
     on bs.blocksequenceid = bsp.blocksequenceid  left outer join
     partpositions pp
     on bsp.partid = pp.partid
group by bs.blocksequenceid, pp.positionid
order by bs.blocksequenceid;
```

This gives you little control over *which* partid is chosen.

Comment: The second statement helped in terms of removing duplicates, but now I'm getting:

    S054 for P3 and P4 when I want S036 for P4

basically I'm convinced that I need to add some column to my tables, some info is missing.

how would I tell the database that for this blocksequence this part is in this position? should I add  P1 P2 P3 P4 columns to the blocksequences table or is it better to just add the column positionid to the blocksequenceparts table? and then how would I select?

Comment: You need to add the position to `blocksequenceparts`, so the join can be on two keys.